# How to prove "lactose intolerance" is a real thing people from 1000AD

Tags: science-based, alternate-history, science-in-society

There was a theory that the conflict between Viking settlers and native people in Newfoundland region of Canada in 1000 AD started when the Viking settler offered milk to the lactose-intolerant natives, which made them sick. In my story, two young people from the two sides, through the help of the divine, realized that this is the case. However, they need to explain to their people and avert a war. How should they prove the concept of "lactose intolerant" is a real thing to these people from 1000 AD using materials and concepts they have at the time?

Comment: This question seems more story-based than worldbuilding based, which this site has a policy against.

Comment: @SquidKid999 but I am asking for a scientific method to explain the concept of lactose intolerant?

Comment: I don't understand what is there to explain more than "milk does not agree with the Skraelings". It is a common fact of life known since always that not all people can eat *all* kinds of food. Some people get mildly unpleasant symptoms if they drink milk; stop giving them milk.

Comment: I'm unsure how this is about building a fictional world. Explaining a thing to a group or individual is a communication challenge. Regardless of how you communicate or explain a thing you're not establishing some fact of your world.

Comment: I'd say: research the period, the every-day lives, the languages involved, the religious concepts of the two cultures - then re-ask this question on [writing.se]. My two rupees worth.

Comment: 1000 years ago people don't even understand what is allergy. They would make up superstitious reasons behind the illness. In this case, they think the Vikings give them poison and that is why they make war. I need an explanation acceptable to people at the time

Comment: It's ok that you want an explanation that makes sense to someone but formulating explanations is not going to establish some fact of your world. As such it is off topic to be asking about it on this site.

Comment: It sounds like what you're really asking is how to _prove_ that lactose intolerance is real. _Explaining_ it is easy. It may be a good idea to edit your question by changing "explain" to "prove."

Comment: This is absolutely not why conflict started between the northmen and the first peoples.  That started because the first time the northmen encountered local inhabitants, they shot at them with arrows, and called them "wretches" (skraelings).  This is very well documented, so I have no idea where your lactose story is coming from.

Comment: Why did your "help of the divine" not provide all the answers? "Ignoring the failure of your "divine," can you clarify whether you're Asking how to prove anything to people from 1,000AD, or to prove to anyone that lactose intolerance is real, or what? 

Can you say which theory said the conflict between Viking settlers and Newfoundland natives started when the Vikings offered milk to the lactose-intolerant natives, which made them sick?

Can you say how those lactose-intolerant natives tolerated their mothers' milk?

Comment: To all those asking about "why divine", and "why lactose-intolerant", I need a conflict that kids can solve, and racial tension that is oh-so-normal in 1000AD won't help my story. And also I want to show that humans can do things too without relying on the divines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pale Skin = Milk Drinker

Your characters bring up how some people have negative reactions to different plants and animals, and this is often shared between close siblings. The pale skin of the Norse signifies that their ancestor spirits gave them a resistance to illness coming from milk, but the ancestors of the natives did not give this gift.

(Basically genes and allergies without saying either)

Comment: But how to prove the milk is not a poison or is not poisoned? That is where the misunderstanding happens

Comment: @FaitoDayo Have one of the vikings drink some milk, then have one of the natives drink it from the same glass. Logically, the native will get sick, but the Viking won't, so then they know that it wasn't the milk that was poisoned. It just happens that the natives are allergic.

Comment: Note that this scenario might work in specific contexts, but that the genes for digesting lactose as an adult persist in various non-Caucasian populations.  For instance, one of the factors that led to the horrific Hutu - Tutsi ethnic cleansing years ago was that the Tutsi are more commonly able to digest lactose and kept cattle, as opposed to the agrarian Hutu who are more likely to be lactose-intolerant. European colonizers gave political preference to the Tutsi, leading to later conflict. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origins_of_Hutu,_Tutsi_and_Twa#Genetic_studies

Comment: Meanwhile, the Romans were often lactose-intolerant: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22romans%22+%22lactose+intolerance%22

Answer (score 8):

**We Vikings are big babies.**

Babies drink milk.  That is true for Amerinds, Vikings and all other humans.  But in a lot of places including the Americas the human populations grow out of drinking milk.

Not the Vikings.  They are big babies and they stay thirsty for milk all their lives.  They are seriously large babies and they drink more milk than their mothers can provide.  When they get big they switch to animal milk because animals are big.

This will make sense to the Amerinds and they will feel good about it - "big babies.  Heh.  Too true, too true.  It explains a lot."  It will make sense to the Vikings too though they might not feel as good about it.  Ordinary Vikings don't really need to hear that.

Best of all is that it is actually pretty accurate.

Answer (score 6):

People are not stupid. just give them a physical demonstration. Get your viking kid to drink half a pint of milk in front of them to show that the vikings had no idea it was poisonous to the skraelings and gave it in good faith.

They'll work it out but only if they want to.

I've had to teach technical things to people with another language, physical demonstration is the best way.

Trying esoteric explanations as suggested elsewhere is a bad idea. These are intelligent, practical people. Lie to them at your peril. They don't take dishonesty lightly.